# How to resolve error that happens when I add a dependency (manifest merging)

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I am trying to use *Sweet Alert Dialog*([here](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog)) in my project but I face a problem.
I am following the README.md file but I don't know where to place the following in android studio:

**MAVEN**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.pedant.sweetalert</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

I've succesfully modified the build.gradle project-level but I don't know what to do with this..

My module gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vogella.android.service.receiver.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    //Sweet alert dialog
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'


}
```

project-level gradle file:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And that's the error I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value= 
(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-43
is also present at [com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0] 
AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at 
AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)

Comment: not really on-topic, but that library you want to use is really outdated. Get something newer. I used it as well and only got problems with Gradle.

Comment: @ZUNJAE is this why although I have add these in my gradle file it doesn't work?

Comment: You're using unmaintained project, try this fork instead: https://github.com/F0RIS/sweet-alert-dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look closely this is about `maven` repository. You should go for `gradle.` it will work. Go into your module gradle file and in dependency tag write dependency and after that write reporitories and put mavenCentral in it.

```
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
}
```

By looking at your logs the problem is in your manifest merging:

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 app:replace="android:icon
```

Comment: I already have done this. I have added mavenCentral() in allprojects{ repositories {} and the compile statement

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos then what issue you faced while implementing this approach ?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos you have imported this library and now you use it ? What do want exactly ?

Comment: check my post. The library isn't imported and I am getting an error message for some reason

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos and looking at the error message your problem is not that library but merging of manifest files. Open your manifest file and then click merged manifests at bottom it will show you the problem fix it there and you will be good to go.

Comment: So is there any conflict in manifest files? 
I still cannot resolve this but thank you for your help

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos I am pretty much sure the problem is in your manifest files not in the library. And opening your manifest file and then clicking merger manifest tab below, you will know where the problem is :)/

Comment: One more thing you can actually see from logs where the problem is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173974/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-nikoloutsos-and-umair).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app level gradle and sync again.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```